# SQL - Select multiple row ranges, but skip rows between ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, I have:

[image]

But I need:

[image]

What I need to do is select multiple ranges where each range begins on 'AppStart' and ends on the first encounter of 'PossibleEnd'.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3. I can do the pivot for the final result I need, it's selecting the ranges that I can't figure out.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Question: How Second range  `End` before the `Start`? Also what you want on `<columns_in_between>`?

Answer (score 0):

Well ok, this query will give you all the starts

```
 SELECT row_num 
 FROM table_name_you_did_not_say
 WHERE event='AppStart'
```

and this gives you the ends

```
 SELECT row_num 
 FROM table_name_you_did_not_say
 WHERE event='PossibleEnd'
```

What you want to do is join these based on a row ordering -- you can use a windowing function to do this:

```
 SELECT Start.row_num as StartNumber, Ends.row_number as EndNumber
 FROM (
   SELECT row_num, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY row_num ACC) as RN
   FROM table_name_you_did_not_say
   WHERE event='AppStart'
 ) Starts
 JOIN (
   SELECT row_num, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY row_num ACC) as RN
   FROM table_name_you_did_not_say
   WHERE event='PossibleEnd'
 ) Ends ON Starts.RN = Ends.RN
```

Comment: @EvanCarroll -- you edited my answer to move the code over by one space?  Why?

Answer (score 0):

Hogan's answer is a good one, but if windowing functions are too complicated for you, here is a simpler solution:

```
SELECT
    start_row,
    MIN(end_row) AS end_row
FROM
    (SELECT
        row_num AS start_row
    FROM
        table_name
    WHERE
        event = 'AppStart'
    ) AS starts
    ,
    (SELECT
        row_num AS end_row
    FROM
        table_name
    WHERE
        event = 'PossibleEnd'
    ) AS ends
WHERE
    end_row > start_row
GROUP BY
    start_row
```

---

Some explanations:

- select all starting indexes and all ending indexes
- join those two sub-queries with a condition that the end must be after the start
- group starting indexes to get the minimal ending point

To get "columns in between" just surround the above query with

```
SELECT
    start_row,
    (SELECT
        array_agg(row_num)
    FROM
        table_name
    WHERE
        row_num > start_row AND
        row_num < end_row
    ) AS columns_in_between,
    end_row
FROM (
    ... the above query goes here
) AS X
```

The result is:

```
start_row   |columns_in_between |end_row
------------+-------------------+--------
8           |{9,10,11}          |12
13          |                   |14
1           |{2,3,4}            |5
```